# Pasar de POINT a LINESTRING en geopandas

Tags: python, geocodificación

Consulta, tengo el problema que quiero pasar un archivo con datos POINT a LINESTRING, el cual originalmente era solo coordenadas y que lo pasé a POINT, el código es el siguiente:

```
coord = [Point(x, y) for x, y in zip(df.latitude, df.longitude)]
df1 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=coord, crs ="EPSG:4326")
df2 = df1.groupby(['line_code','direction','expedition_id'])['geometry']
print(LineString(df2))
```

Pero con el print me arroja el siguiente error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)<ipython-input-79-41a34ee267df> in <cell line: 2>()
  1 df2 = df1.groupby(['line_code','direction','expedition_id'])['geometry']
----> 2 print(LineString(df2)) 
  3 frames 
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/shapely/geometry/linestring.py in <listcomp>(.0)
 62                         return o.coords[0]
 63                     else:
---> 64                         return [float(c) for c in o]
 65 
 66                 coordinates = [_coords(o) for o in coordinates]
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a real number, not 'tuple'
```

Y se supone que, acorde a lo que busque y a la documentación de LINESTRING, esta ocupa tuplas, entonces no sé cuál sería el error, porque la conversión de coordenadas a POINT en la primera línea sale correcto, se genera una columna de geometry con POINT, pero al momento de agrupar y tratar de convertir el conjunto de POINT por grupo a LINESTRING me arroja ese error, incluso traté de cambiar el crs y tampoco, por favor ayuda.